# applyBindings in main.js for multiple view models

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-validation

I am developing an app using KnockoutJS and have now reached the point where I want to add a second view model.  Here is my main.js with my first view model :

```
    require(['knockout', 'viewModels/teamViewModel',, 'domReady!'], function (ko, teamViewModel) {

    //validation
    ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';

    ko.validation.init({
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: null
    });

    ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(new teamViewModel());
});
```

I reference main.js in my Teams.cshtml view like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/Scripts/main.js" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Now I want to add a second view model, I have changed main.js to this :

```
    require(['knockout', 'viewModels/teamViewModel', 'viewModels/fixtureViewModel', 'domReady!'], function (ko, teamViewModel, fixtureViewModel) {

    //validation
    ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';

    ko.validation.init({
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: null
    });

    ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(new teamViewModel());
    ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(new fixtureViewModel());
});
```

And I have added a reference to main.js in my Fixtures.cshtml view like in the Teams.cshtml.

But I get the error :

```
You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element
```

Is the correct way to do this to have separate main.js file for each view model (such as mainTeam.js, mainFixture.js), or is there a way to do this in one main.js file? Or am I approaching this in the wrong way entirely?

Comment: You can use [Knockout postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) to handle communication between viewmodels, however I'd second @Sharihin in that Knockout is 'meant' to have only one call to `applyBindings`. In your case you could 'fix' this simply by doing: `var masterVM = { team: new teamViewModel(), fixture: new fixtureViewModel() };`, apply bindings to the 'master' viewmodel, and update your HTML accordingly.

Comment: If you have to switch between views you can do this easily with component binding. More information [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) and some real example [here](https://github.com/crissdev/spa-template-ko).

Comment: I went with the answer from Tyblitz and upvoted the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Knockout.js is designed for "one global viewmodel for application".

You can make root ViewModel, which will handle page routing and loading/initializing child models.

Simplest way to do this is to define

`<div data-bind="template: { name: activePage().template, data: activePage().data } ></div>`

in your main html file and create observable with fields `template`(id of template) and `data`(child viewmodel) in viewmodel.

Or, if you just want to make two "instances" of knockout running at the same time but for different DIVs, you could use `ko.applyBindingsToNode` or `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` specifying different HTML elements as containers